# What is a replacement method for Task.Run in .NET 4.0 using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I got this program that gives me syntax error "System.Threading.Tasks.task does not contain a definition for Run."

I am using VB 2010 .NET 4.0
Any ideas? any replacements for Run in .net 4.0?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChatApp
{
class ChatProg
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<int> wakeUp = DoWorkAsync(2000,"Waking up");
        Task.WaitAll(wakeUp);
    }

    static Task<int> DoWorkAsync(int milliseconds, string name)
    {

        //error appears below on word Run
        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("* starting {0} work", name);
                Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("* {0} work one", name);
                return 1;
            });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try this Task.Factory.StartNew()
Please refer below link :http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: i got same issue but the problem that it has risk while i am  reading about this issue so is threading good choose insted??? if yes please provide me with details  example about threading because this my first time working with thread

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It looks like [`Task.Factory.StartNew<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321455(v=vs.100).aspx) is what you're after.

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => {
    // ...
    return 1;
});
```

Since the compiler can infer the return type, this also works:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // ...
    return 1;
});
```

Comment: Is Run a .NET 4.5 feature?

Comment: @Henryyottabyte yes, apparently: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx

Comment: adding to the answer is this link i found. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: It looks like Task::Factory->StartNew in C++/CLI

Comment: It's important to know that this code does not behave identically to Task.Run.

Answer (score 10):

The [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607134/3745022), unfortunately, is not exactly [correct](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html):

> Unfortunately, the only overloads for StartNew that take a
>   TaskScheduler also require you to specify the CancellationToken and
>   TaskCreationOptions. This means that in order to use
>   Task.Factory.StartNew to reliably, predictably queue work to the
>   thread pool, you have to use an overload like this:
>
> Task.Factory.StartNew(A, CancellationToken.None,
>   TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);

So the closest thing to `Task.Run` in 4.0 is something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Starts the new <see cref="Task"/> from <paramref name="function"/> on the Default(usually ThreadPool) task scheduler (not on the TaskScheduler.Current).
/// It is a 4.0 method nearly analogous to 4.5 Task.Run.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the return value.</typeparam>
/// <param name="factory">The factory to start from.</param>
/// <param name="function">The function to execute.</param>
/// <returns>The task representing the execution of the <paramref name="function"/>.</returns>
public static Task<T> StartNewOnDefaultScheduler<T>(this TaskFactory factory, Func<T> function)
{
    Contract.Requires(factory != null);
    Contract.Requires(function != null);

    return factory
        .StartNew(
            function,
            cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None,
            creationOptions: TaskCreationOptions.None,
            scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

that can be used like:

```
Task
    .Factory
    .StartNewOnDefaultScheduler(() => 
        result);
```

Answer (score 5):

I changed your code with `Task.Factory.StartNew` check detail [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

```
 static Task<int> DoWorkAsync(int milliseconds, string name)
        {


            //error appears below on word Run
            return   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("* starting {0} work", name);
                Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("* {0} work one", name);
                return 1;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you're using [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) here you go:

```
return TaskEx.Run(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("* starting {0} work", name);
    Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("* {0} work one", name);
    return 1;
});
```