# Task does not contain a definition for Run method

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I tried to implement multithreading in my code, 1st time. When i tried to use

```
Task T = Task.Run(() => { });
```

Visual Studio is still underlines Run() with statement "Task does not contain a definition 'Run' "

I'm using System.Threading.Tasks;
Internet knows nothing about this problem

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Can you please isolate the failure into minimal example file and add that it to your question including .NET version and references of your project?

Comment: in this project .NET Framework 4

Comment: Add `System.Threading` library through nuget

Comment: May be ambiguous with another namespace, if your using System.Threading namespace then try `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run();`

Answer (score 27):

`.NET 4.0` does not have a `Task.Run` method. Instead you can use:

`Task T = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });`

Which you can learn more about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321455(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 12):

Task.Run was introduced in .NET 4.5, you are using .net 4.0. If you can't upgrade your project you can include the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) NuGet package to introduce a `TaskEx.Run(` to add it in to .net 4.0.

Comment: I was using .net framework 4.5 but it still said that it doesn't contain any method called `Run`.. Now I upgraded to 4.7 and still the same error. So it's not only  the .net version. it must be something else. can anybody help me?

Comment: You will need to ask a separate question with a full code sample that reproduces the problem we can copy and paste. Recreate the problem on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and include a link to the code in your question. Make sure you have the full code in the question too.

Comment: ah, I just figured it out. i was using the namespace `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data` Which had the class `Task`. So It was referring to this Task instead of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`. Common mistake. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, is not exactly [correct](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) that `Task.Run` is same as `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607048/what-is-a-replacement-method-for-task-run-in-net-4-0-using-c/41940287#41940287) answer , it is given the closest thing to `Task.Run` in 4.0 which is something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Starts the new <see cref="Task"/> from <paramref name="function"/> on the Default(usually ThreadPool) task scheduler (not on the TaskScheduler.Current).
/// It is a 4.0 method nearly analogous to 4.5 Task.Run.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the return value.</typeparam>
/// <param name="factory">The factory to start from.</param>
/// <param name="function">The function to execute.</param>
/// <returns>The task representing the execution of the <paramref name="function"/>.</returns>
public static Task<T> StartNewOnDefaultScheduler<T>(this TaskFactory factory, Func<T> function)
{
    Contract.Requires(factory != null);
    Contract.Requires(function != null);

    return factory
        .StartNew(
            function,
            cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None,
            creationOptions: TaskCreationOptions.None,
            scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

that can be used like:

```
Task
    .Factory
    .StartNewOnDefaultScheduler(() => 
        result);
```

But `Task.Run` is a nice wrapper over `Task.Factory.StartNew` introduced in `.NET 4.5`.

But for your situation, when you need it for `multithreading` operations, just use it.

> But don't forget.

You should prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew` if you use `async` code.

In this [article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) , Stephen Curry gives two reason that `StartNew` method is dangerous:

- **Does not understand async delegates.**
- **Confusing default scheduler.**

Comment: What is the world is `Contract`? `The name 'Contract' does not exist in the current context`